# Copying files from OSX to samba, force create mode not working

Tags: samba, mac-osx, copy

I have a problem whereby I have set up a samba share with these parrameters:

[Design]
path = "/sec/projects/design"
writeable = yes
browsable = yes
valid users = @design
force group = design
force create mode = 0775
force directory mode = 770

When I copy a file from removable storage which has the permissions set as 644 as a user from the design group the file receives the permissions 644 rather than being set to 775.

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question:
[Permission issues with Samba and OS X](https://serverfault.com/questions/81231/permission-issues-with-samba-and-os-x)

Read the comments to the answers as well.